# "Saved Queries" button disappeared

Tags: google-bigquery

Has anyone else ever had the Saved Queries button disappear in BigQuery? Happened to me a few days ago. So far, I haven't found an explanation or anyone else in my company (or anywhere) that it has happened to.  I've tried both Safari and Chrome.  It survives reboots.  It happens on both a Mac and Windows box.  So it seems to be tied to my profile somehow...

I also started getting a "Saved queries" section at the top of one of our projects which does appear to have my stuff along with all shared queries from everyone else.  I can't limit that view to just my own queries though like I could in Saved Queries and it doesn't appear to be a section that is searched when doing a Search.  It only shows a subset of the total queries and clicking the "show more" link does add more, but intermingles them within the existing list, so you have to scroll through the whole thing each time you click "show more".  Less than ideal for sure.

Any insight is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: looks like abc test and you are lucky to get into it :o)

Comment: A colleague suggested the same....  Do they seek feedback at some point?  I have a lot for them....  :)

Comment: i am not a google employee so cannot answer - but I would expect feedback is always welcome :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default BigQuery uses the new UI. To revert back to the old UI, you can click **"DISABLE EDITOR TABS"**. "Saved Queries" will be back on the UI as well as  the tabs "Personal queries" and "Project queries".

**Revert to old UI:**

[image]

**See reverted UI:**

[image]

**To send a feedback with regards to the new UI:**

1. Open any [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries)
2. Click "Send feedback"
3. Choose "BigQuery Product feedback"

> [image]

4. Fill up the form with your feed back

Comment: Thank you Ricco...  Before I undo something I can't redo, aren't "Editor Tabs" the ability to have multiple "tabbed" queries in one browser tab?  If so, I've successfully had (and use heavily) that for the full time (6+ months) that I've been using BQ.  The missing Saved Queries started sometime in the past week or so.

Comment: went ahead and did this and see that i can get back to the tabbed view if i miss it enough.  this did let me get back to my saved queries in a manner that I was previously familiar with....  thank you!!

Comment: Yes you can always revert back to the tabbed view. Feel free to submit any feedback as it will help improve the product =)